# Kendo UI tab strap with angular is not showing new tab - Caching is the issue how to stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

There is a tabstrip being used and in the browser I can see 3 tabs
2 are active and last is not

Upgrade Product | Membership Info | Agent Notes

I want to ADD another tab,  but 1. I can't get the data to display, nor understand where to find the code for how this kendo js works.

This is what I see

```
  <div kendo-tab-strip="agent.tabstrip" k-content-urls="[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null]" k-options="agent.tabOptions" style="margin-top: 1em">
        <!-- tab list -->
        <ul>
            <li class="k-state-active">Upgrade Product</li>
            <li>Membership Info</li>
            <li>Update Payment</li>
            <li class="k-state-disabled" enabled="false" >Agent Notes</li>
        </ul>


        <div style="padding: 1em; height:800px">
            <div ng-include src="'/apps/common/atb/tabs/contactinfo/contactinfo.html'"></div>
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 1em; height:850px">
            <div ng-include src="'/apps/common/atb/tabs/memberinfo/memberinfo.html'"></div>

        </div>
        <div style="padding: 1em; height:800px">
            My test - but Update Payment does not even display in browser :( 
        </div>


        <div style="padding: 1em; height:450px">
            <div ng-include src="'/apps/common/atb/tabs/agentnotes/agentnotes.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the `<li>Update Payment</li>` to show up

Where do I need to look with regards to `kendo-tab-strip` and `agent.tabstrip` and the `k-content-urls` and then `k-options="agent.tabOptions"`  ?

I looked through Kendo tab documentation,  I'm not sure why someone made this real "fun"  :/

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to put an attribute on the inner element. Try this.

```
<div style="padding: 1em; height:800px">
    <div ng-include >My test - but Update Payment does not even display in browser :(</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nope...  even this template page, if I create an outer div - It doesn't show up   !   :(      `<div>test outside</div>`

Comment: Ok, seems the problem to be caching!   I tried both chrome and incognito mode and it wasn't until I used the network dev tool tab and refreshed the specific page did it not cache ,  so what a nightmare!   How to I stop caching!

Comment: It depends. On the server side, there are numerous ways to cache. You will get a better answer if you ask a web server/framework cache specific question. I can answer all the techniques for .net caching, however, you will get a more detailed response if you ask the question with the server side framework you are using as a tag.